Book about a guy that uses a car to travel to different Earths
The book starts somewhere in the wilderness and the main character (MC) is visiting his grandfather, who is a genius. He finds that his grandfather is missing and when he looks around, he finds a car. I don't remember if his grandfather gave him a message or not but the MC turns on the car and gets transferred to a different place with a patch of earth.
The Earth he went to was one where Nikola Tesla managed to make his energy harvest device work, but it made everything on the Earth electrified, although some things evolved to use the electricity. Some humans did too. And some objects have perpetual motion.
At the end of the book, he finds a girl and brings her back. He tried to take a bike that had perpetual motion, but a tornado or something like that was hunting all the perpetual motion things and he lost it.
In the other books (I think it was a 5 or 6-novel series), he goes to a prehistoric Earth, an Earth that was eaten by a slime, and an Earth where corporations control everything and make you pay money for driving. By the end, he gets hunted by these aliens that have tentacles on their faces and has to be careful not to get caught.
I read this a couple of years ago. Every cover has a car on it. Like the Back to the Future car. One I specifically remember had the car and a slime girl on the front of it. The color of her slime was like an oil color. Also the cover was a style like Eric Vall's novels.
That's about it. I hope someone knows what I'm talking about.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember the cover art?

I read this a couple years ago. Every cover at has a car in it. Like the back to the future car. On I specifically remember was the car and a slime girl on the front of it. The color of her slime was like and oil color. And I ment back

Just from the title I was betting on a Zelazny book, but nope.

Also the cover was a style like Eric vall's novels

Just ruling out https://www.goodreads.com/series/214098-where-the-hell-is-tesla

Nope thanks for the suggestion though.

@thebeastwalls: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

The Monster Girl Base series, written by Logan Jacobs. Book 1, simply titled Monster Girl Base, was first published as a Kindle e-book on June 9, 2020. (That's according to the details given in the Amazon listing which I linked to the book's title). There were seven books in the series, and after the first one, Logan Jacobs would use an appropriate numeral at the end of the title for each new volume. Monster Girl Base 2, Monster Girl Base 3, and so forth -- very simple!
I was in the same boat you were. I vaguely recognized the series from your description, but couldn't for the life of me remember the title or author. So I had to dig around a bit until I found it.
Here are some points which correspond well with your description. (Mainly taken from the first volume, which established the basic premise.)
Plot Points

As the story begins, the narrator is a young man living in Michigan and applying for jobs via the Internet (implicitly in our own version of Earth or something extremely similar to it) when he receives an e-mail from his cranky old Uncle Sol, an inventor and conspiracy theorist. It has a video attachment which the narrator (Dave) watches. Summarizing like crazy: Sol states that this video was set to be mailed to Dave if Sol didn't log into a computer system for three days running, which would probably mean he was either dead or being vigorously interrogated by "spooks" (implicitly, agents of the CIA or some other intelligence-type of federal agency). He wants Dave to go over to Sol's workshop and active the timers on explosive charges to blow everything up before the spooks can get their hands on it all. Especially the old 1972 Lincoln automobile -- which, as I recall, no longer runs.

Dave is sitting inside that car when the aforementioned spooks show up and surround him, guns pointed at him, yelling at him to get out of the car. Dave accidentally pushes a button or something with his elbow, and the strange technology which Sol had hidden in the car fires up and teleports the car, Dave, and a circular patch of ground around the car, to the corresponding geographical location in an alternate timeline.

Eventually, Dave learns (I think from another recorded message from Sol) that, as an evasive maneuver to avoid being tracked across the multiverse by Sol's enemies, every few days the car automatically will teleport again, moving sideways in time to a different parallel Earth on each occasion. Each time this occurs, it takes along a larger circular patch of ground than before.

One of the worlds he later visits is the one where Nicola Tesla had an experiment backfire and the catastrophic results permanently electrified pretty much everything -- including bringing lots of machinery to life, and including bestowing electrical superpowers upon all those humans who survived the catastrophe, and all of their descendants, over a century later -- including a charming young woman who becomes one of the narrator's girlfriends. (I think that visit occurred in Book 2. At any rate, that girl appears on the cover of Book 2.)

Dave gradually acquires a harem of girlfriends as he goes along. The "Monster Girl" phrase in the series title is meant to reflect the fact that none of these lovely young ladies can qualify as "baseline human," either because of superpowers, as with the girl who has human ancestry but can generate electrical shocks, or because they were never members of Homo Sapiens to begin with. (The alien slime girl certainly wasn't.)


To prove it's the same series, here's the cover-image from Monster Girl Base 3. It's the one you described from memory, with an alien slime girl sitting on the hood of the car. She is a small portion of the slime which had invaded and overcome all of Planet Earth in that timeline. When the car teleported away, some of the local slime went with it to the next timeline on the itinerary, and "she" then decided it was time to learn how to talk to these other travelers. (If I recall correctly -- it's been a few years, and I don't own a copy of the relevant volume -- what we see in the picture is not a form she had ever used before meeting Dave et al.; it's simply what she chooses to look like in order to make a good impression on Dave and his other friends when she starts talking to them.)


Yes thank you so much
